# Django templates seems that is not loading Backbone.js in correct order

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js

I am using django templates and django compressor to load my javascript files.

base_layout.html:

```
...

<!-- common imports for all templates -->
{% compress js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/materialize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/easychem.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/styling/menu_helper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/backbone.js"></script>
{% endcompress %}

<!-- custom js imports that each template decides to load -->
{% compress js %}
   {% block custom_js %}{% endblock %}
{% endcompress %}

...
```

compoundReportCard.html

```
...
{% block custom_js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/styling/scrollspy_helper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/styling/buttons_helper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/models/Compound.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
...
```

Compound.js

```
var Compound;

Compound = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

When I load the page I get the following error:

> Compound.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not
>   defined(anonymous function) @ Compound.js:4

I got this error before when the file Compound.js loads before backbone.js

But if I do the following:

(Note that now I load the Compound.js file in the base_layout.html file)

base_layout.html

```
      ...
        <!-- common imports for all templates -->
        {% compress js %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/materialize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/easychem.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/styling/menu_helper.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/underscore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/api/backbone.js"></script>
<!--- note this!!! -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/models/Compound.js"></script>
        {% endcompress %}

        <!-- custom js imports that each template decides to load -->
        {% compress js %}
           {% block custom_js %}{% endblock %}
        {% endcompress %}
        ...
```

I don't get any error.

It seems that the django templates load the javascript files in different orders in the first scenario, when I use the "custom_js" block. Am I right? or am I misunderstanding something? how can I solve this? I would like to load the Compound.js file only for the compoundReportCard.html

Comment: the browser actually loads your JS files not django, the django templates are just creating the end result html.  Your problem is elsewhere, viewing source will show you the order django put them in, which is the order you specified.  if you put this compound script just before the </body> tag do you get the same results?

Comment: Thank you for you comment, indeed my problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I accidentally had an extra "{% endblock %}" that was causing the issue.